# Processing sound is slower than the original

Tags: java, audio, processing

My program is essentially this:

```
import processing.sound.*;

void setup() {
    SoundFile file = new SoundFile(this, "E:/Coding/Tetris/data/Soundtrack.mp3");
    file.loop();
}

void draw() {}
```

When I execute it, the audio is about 1.08 times slower than the original sound.

Of course I can just add `file.rate(1.08);` but that's just a workaround and doesn't actually "fix" the problem. How can the slowed down audio be explained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"How can the slowed down audio be explained?"

48000 / 44100 = 1.088435374

The change in speed is likely due to the difference in frames per second. Your source sound was probably recorded at 48000 and the playback is running at 44100 fps.

There is a tutorial on [Using Files and Format Converters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html) which might be helpful in terms of working with the asset, but I don't know that 48000 is a supported format. Also, whatever library you are using to decode the .mp3 may also pose limitations.

I'd consider using a tool like Audacity to convert the asset to 44100, prior to bringing it into Java as an asset. Or if you are working with a sound designer, let them know you need the assets they deliver to be encoded at 44100 fps.

But if it's easy to play back the asset at 1.08, maybe that is an acceptable path of least resistance?

Comment: It is definitely a sample rate problem, but `processing.sound` is an ultra simplified library and ideally the user shouldn't have to deal with conversion. This is definitely the route to a fix, but I still believe [flagging an issue](https://github.com/processing/processing-sound/issues) is a good route to go down.

Comment: That said, there is the [configuration class for the processing.sound library](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/sound/Sound.html), it should be just a case of [forcing sample rate](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/sound/Sound_sampleRate_.html) to `soundfile.sampleRate()` (not documented)

Comment: Excellent catch though! Can't believe I missed it. I can edit in a short code sample should you be short on time.

Comment: I ended up converting my file to .wav (using editing software) and it plays at normal speed now

Comment: @R.B. for holism and help to anyone else with similar problems, could you have a check of the properties of your `mp3` and your new `wav` and confirm the sampling rates of each?

Comment: @fdcpp Both are 48kHz, I guess `processing.sound` handles mp3 worse than wav

Comment: @R.B. I can't recreate this. Could you [flag an issue on processing.sound](https://github.com/processing/processing-sound/issues)? It would be greatly appreciated